# interpreting python kde plot y-axis

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

Given the below code, I'm a bit unsure about how to interpret the y-axes. I understand that a gaussian is drawn over each datapoint and then summed to produce the curve, but I'm not sure how the widths or heights of those gaussians are determined. I would have thought that the `sum_nums` variable would produce a plot with a much larger y-axis...

```
some_probs = np.random.normal(0.8, 0.1, 20)
some_nums = np.random.normal(2200, 600, 20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.distplot(some_probs, ax=ax[0])
sns.distplot(some_nums, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Could anybody shed light on this for me?

Comment: _I would have thought that the `sum_nums` variable would produce a plot with a much larger y-axis_. 

The total probability mass for any distribution _must_ sum to unity (1). In the first example, this mass is spread out over only a small support (say, about `[0, 2.0]`). In the second, it is spread over a range of many thousands - yet it still needs to sum to _only_ 1. This implies the mass around any one point must be considerably smaller compared to the first plot.

Comment: Can you go into detail about *why* you would expect a different plot? It's hard to know where you're lost, and hence to know what you need to have explained.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I just don't understand how to interpret the y-axis. I just thought the density needs to sum to 1 thus the y-axes for both plots should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @N.Wouda what exactly do you mean by "only a small support", and where is the `[0, 2]` coming from (give nthat the probs variable takes on values only 0 to 1)? Thanks

Comment: The *integral* over the probability distribution is 1. Very roughly, on the left you have `(1-0.5)*2 == 1`. On the right you have `(3500-1000)*0.0004 == 1`.

Comment: @ffrost that restriction does hold for _discrete_ distributions, but the KDE attempts to find a _continuous_ distribution matching your data. For [continuous density functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), there is no such restriction, other than that the _integral_ of these values sums to unity.